Why is $2\sum_{k=a}^{b}ki^k=(1+i)i^a-i^a+i^b+(1-i)i^bb$
I am studying to skip into 10th grade, and on the curriculum, it has a section titled "Investigation of large sums and products of consecutive powers if $i$" (I kid you not) immediately after "Introduction to the complex number $i$" and "Introduction of the sigma and pi notation."
It gives problems in the form $\sum\limits_{k=a}^{b}ki^k$. I put this equation in WolframAlpha, and here is the answer to it: $$2\sum\limits_{k=a}^{b}ki^k=(1+i)i^a-i^a+i^b+(1-i)i^bb$$
How did they get this result?


ADDITIONAL INFO:
Obviously, $i^n=i^{n+4}$ because $i^{n+4}=i^ni^4=i^n(1)=i^n$, so there is definitely a pattern here. Please explain it like I'm dumb so I can understand.

NO INDUCTION plz, I want derivation.

The LHS is a sum from an arithmetico-geometric sequence, then there are simplifications using the properties of $i$.

1/ Please recheck your expression, I believe it's incorrect. $\quad$ 2/ Are you familiar with induction? If yes, show that the statement is true for $f(a, a)$ and also that $f(a, b) \Rightarrow f(a, b+1)$.

Define $S = \sum_{k=a}^{b}ki^{k}$ then $$i \cdot S = \sum_{k=a}^{b}ki^{k+1} = ai^{a+1}+\sum_{k=a}^{b-1}(k+1)i^{k+2}  = ai^{a+1}-\sum_{k=a}^{b-1}(k+1)i^{k}.$$
Adding the two equations, $$S(1+i) = ai^{a+1}+bi^b - \sum_{k=a}^{b-1}i^k$$
The sum on the right side is a geometric series and can be simplified as $\sum_{k=a}^{b-1}i^k = \frac{i^a-i^b}{1-i}$. Thus, $S$ is given by $$ \boxed{S  = \frac{1-i}{2}\left(ai^{a+1}+bi^b \right)-\frac{1}{2}(i^a-i^b)}$$
